# Is there a way to look one level down from the current directory without explicitly calling for it

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Here is the code I have. Is there a way to look into all the files/folders in folderName? I'm assuming I'll use a nested for loop to iterate through each file/folder in folderName.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import shutil
import numpy

#set the destination folder to variable
destination = 'G:\\path\\to\\destination\\'

matrix = []
matrix.append([])
matrix.append([])

#client folder name in index 0 of matrix, client performance folder in index 1 of matrix
for folderName in os.listdir(destination):
    matrix[0].append(folderName) #client folder name
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right you need to go recursively through all the subfolders ...

For this purpose you should use the os.walk function like this :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(): 
    #do something  like  matrix[0].append(folderName) #client folder name
```

root will be taken as "current", as long as it is exausted and then will be changed with the next one from the dirs-list

Good luck :)

Remark:

os.listdir takes the content only of the current folder and doesn't go deeper in the structure of subfolders

Comment: I found a way to do it. just created a variable called tempPath = destination + folderName + '\\'

Answer (score 0):

Documentation and examples for os.walk provided [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) so really no need to repeat.